# Ruby Savon compared to Java Axis

Tags: java, ruby, wsdl, apache-axis, savon

I'm trying to use the Yodlee soap APIs. They give examples with Apache Axis
Any perspectives on using Ruby and Savon versus Java and Axis?

With Ruby/Savon, it seems that the best thing to do is to skip using the WSDL files and generate the requests based on examples from the Java/Axis program. I tried using the WSDL feature of Savon, but I could not get it to work with the many embedded types and namespaces in the very complex WSDLs.

Looking at the Java/Axis code, there's a huge amount of generated code that isolates the Java developer from knowing about the XML. Has anybody ever tried to replicate Axis in the Ruby world?

Thanks.